# dependency injection factory module another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try use dependency injection factory to module another , but it not working.I working with ionic framework and angular.

```
angular.module('starter.services1', []).factory('Test 1', function($http) {
  return {
    show_text: function() {
      console.log(test1)
    }
  }
});
angular.module('starter.services2', ['starter.services1']).factory('Test2', function($http, Test1) {
  return {
    Test1.show_text();
  }
});
```

> Error: Cannot read property 'show_text' of undefined

Comment: Factory name must not have space in name `Test 1`. Change it to `Test1` while defining factory.

Comment: Thanks! But after I changed it's still not working. `angular.module('starter.services1', []).factory('Test1', function($http) {
  return {
    show_text: function() {
     console.log(test1)
    }
  }
});
angular.module('starter.services2', ['starter.services1']).factory('Test2', function($http, Test1) {
  return {
   initShow: funtion(){
     Test1.show_text();
   }
  }
});`

Answer (score 3):

Your factory is `Test 1` when defining a factory its better to have names without space , so change it to something without a space,

```
angular.module('starter.services1', []).factory('factorySample1', function($http) {
  return {
    show_text: function() {
      console.log(test1)
    }
  }
});
angular.module('starter.services2', ['starter.services1']).factory('Test2', function($http, factorySample1) {
  return {
    factorySample1.show_text();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems, one is the spelling mistake and `console.log(test1)`. But your code was not working because of spelling mistake at initShow `function`

```js
angular.module('starter.services1', []).factory('Test1', function($http) {
  return {
    show_text: function() {
      console.log('test1')
    }
  }
});
angular.module('starter.services2', ['starter.services1']).factory('Test2', function($http, Test1) {
  return {
    initShow: function() {
      Test1.show_text();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```